# difference between past perfect and past continuos

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

This is a question in my text book and I find that we can use both of the tenses (past perfect and past continuous). However, the answer is to use past perfect in this context. It really makes me confused. Can you guys help me with this?

We were confused when we discovered we *were getting/ had got* lost.

Comment: Not an easy one. I wouldn't say getting lost is a punctive change ('17:57:46. We're not lost. 17:57:47. Now we are.'), but I don't think one would say 'We're getting lost' as often as 'We're lost'. Not that it's in any way wrong. However, 'discover one is getting lost' doesn't sound idiomatic, because 'discover' _is_ punctive; at that point, would you be lost or not? 3/4 lost?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, although the process of getting lost is a gradual one, the discovery of the process occurs when the process is already complete. Thus, we tend to say "We're lost", or "We've got lost" rather than "We're getting lost" when we discover the problem.

In a narrative describing such a situation, then, we are more likely to say:

"we discovered that we had got lost"

rather than

"...that we were getting lost"

-since the second would imply that we discovered it while the process was still happening.

Compare (examples adapted from English Grammar In Use by Raymond Murphy, CUP 2012):

When I came home, John had watched the TV programme

or

When I came home, John was watching the TV programme.

In the first example, the programme was finished at the time I came home (and John was perhaps already in bed). In the second, it was still on TV (and John was still on the sofa, probably eating chocolate).